# Signing Same Version of BlackBerry Application for Different Devices with WebWorks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I'm working on publishing an application with WebWorks.

I want it to work on Playbook, BB10, and older versions of BB that use WebWorks.

First I went to the Playbook Webworks SDK and built the .bar using ...

```
bbwp C:\myapp\myapp.zip -gcsk password -gp12 password -buildId 2
```

Then I went to the BB10 SDK and ran

```
bbwp C:\myapp\myapp.zip -g password --buildId 2
```

But I get back 'this file has been previously signed.'

If I change the buildId it works, but I want to submit both of these files as a filebundle as version 2 of this application.

Does the buildId have anything to do with the application version on App World, or are these values totally unrelated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge after doing this a few times... The buldID which is used while signing is completely unrelated to the version number of the file.

Just use any unique number for the buildId, its for signing purposes only.

The version number of your program is either set through your config.xml or manually when you upload the files to App World.